# What caching options do I have in a windows service hosting WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a windows service that is hosting WCF services.

What caching options do I have inside of a windows service?

Comment: What framework are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are targeting 3.5, your caching options within the confines of your Windows service is somewhat limited.

1. You could custom build something, but I would shy away from that; other people have already done that work and very well too.
2. You could use [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849). That doesn't really run inside your service though, but does have some interesting advantages.
3. [Microsoft's Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) would fit the bill, but it is now deprecated because caching is a part of .NET framework 4.0 and newer (see [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx)).
4. [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is a free, open source project.